# Composite Index, Single Index and Duplicated Column Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, key

I have the following query.
`DataStaging` is a big table has 10 millions rows.

`Product i`s a smaller table has 1000 rows.

We need to find the `product_id` by using the `ref` and there are two `ref (ref1,ref2)`  on the `Product` table, so have to join the table twice.

```
    UPDATE  dbo.DataStaging
    SET     ProductId = COALESCE(Ref1_Pid, Ref2_Pid, 0) 
    FROM    dbo.DataStaging s
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  id [Ref1_Pid] ,
                                Ref1
                        FROM    dbo.Product
                        WHERE   isActive = 1
                      ) p1 ON s.[Ref] = p1.Ref1
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  id [Ref2_Pid] ,
                                Ref2
                        FROM    dbo.Product
                        WHERE   IsActive = 1
                      ) p2 ON s.[Ref] = p1.Ref2
           
    WHERE   s.TypeId = 1
            AND s.StatusId = 2
```

This is a Primary key on the product table PK_Product and I'm free to add Non_Clustered Index.

(1) Three indexes: NC_index on (IsActive), NC_Index on (Ref1), NC_Index on (Ref2)

(2) Two Composite indexes : NC_Index on (IsActive, Ref1), NC_Index on (IsActive, Ref2)

(3) One Composite index: NC_Index on (IsActive, Ref1, Ref2)

for (1) it scans the table using Primary key PK_Product, but not NC index.

for (2) it uses the NC_index Scan on each index.

for (3) It uses the NC_index Scan on the same index but the row size is a double of (2)

As a result, the performance (2) > (3) > (1)

My question is,

why doesn't (1) scan on NC index?

what is the drawback if I create index like (2) or (3)?

Assume the above query is the heaviest process of `Product`, but there are hundreds of `stored procs` using the `product` table with `select` statement with different `where` condition. Is (2) still a good approach than (3) even the performance for the above query is (2) > (3)?

(ignore the index on dataStaging for now)

Answer (score 2):

(1) would require an index join for the index on IsActive and the one on Ref1/Ref2, which it is deeming less optimal.

I would go for a variation on (2) - two filtered indexes with includes:

```
create index IX_Product_Ref1 on Product (Ref1) include(id) where (IsActive = 1)
create index IX_Product_Ref2 on Product (Ref2) include(id) where (IsActive = 1)
```

(3) would only be a good idea if you query IsActive, Ref1 AND Ref2 together.

Also, could you not write your query like this?

```
UPDATE  dbo.DataStaging
    SET     ProductId = isnull(p.id, p2.id) 
FROM    dbo.DataStaging s
LEFT JOIN dbo.Product p ON s.[Ref] = p.Ref1 and p.IsActive = 1
LEFT JOIN dbo.Product p2 ON s.[Ref] = p2.Ref2 and p2.IsActive = 1
WHERE s.TypeId = 1
AND s.StatusId = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer muhmud, i never use a filtered indexes, will read it later. I read from other ppls' post saying `left join ... or..` is worse than use two `left join`, not sure again.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this. In the `or` way, the optimizer will want to use one access path, i.e. index for the Product table. As neither of the indexes above could individually be used, it reverts to a table scan of Product. If you create an index on (Ref1, Ref2), this still is problematic for searching on Ref2. It does use the index, but puts an expensive spool on top of it. I have updated the query.